# Blank pages between pages of the same file and between pages in different files.

Tags: book-design, include, blank-page

I'm writing in the "master document" style, using the `\include` command, and between pages of the same file included and between pages of different files some blank pages appeared. What do I do to make these pages disappear?

My preamble, with the include commands, is:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}

\usepackage[brazil]{babel}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts,wasysym}
\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
\usepackage[top=3cm,left=3cm,right=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\input{Dedicatoria}
\input{Agradecimentos}

\tableofcontents

\input{Cap1}
\input{Cap2}
\input{Cap3}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Are you using `\include` or `\input`? Only the first should behave like that. Your question and your code don't match. Also, indenting lines by four spaces will format them as code.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  You can format code samples by selecting the code and clicking on the 101010 icon.  Your question isn't very clear, however.  You should be using `include{Cap1}` instead of `\input{Cap1}`; although that may not solve your problem.

Comment: @Alan: using `\include` makes only sense when someone also uses `\includeonly`. Otherwise `\input` does the same job and there will be no difference.

Comment: @Rodrigo:, I edited your question a little to make it more clear (IMHO) and I escaped the \include command in bac-ticks as is common here. Please feel free to revert to your original version if you don't like the changes.

Comment: @Carsten Thiel: well, sorry about the misunderstood! I used both (input and include) and both give the same result!

Comment: @Yossi Farjoun: thank you! I want to do what you do, but I don't knew (yet) how could I do! thank you so much!

Comment: @Herbert: That is not true. `\include`'d material is always typeset on a new page, whereas `\input{file}` is almost equivalent to inserting the contents of file.tex verbatim in the current file (only almost because one might have used `\endinput`). Also, `\include` commands cannot be nested. Of course, if file.tex starts with a `\chapter` and is included from the main file, `\input` and `\include` are equivalent.

Comment: @Villemoes: I didn't say, that both are the same! In the original example is the book class used, so chapters will also be start on a new page. I said, that in this case an `\include` makes no sense when not using also `\includeonly`! And that is correct!

Comment: @rodrigo, you can always look at the current (and past) "source" of the posting by clicking on "edit" (on your posts). if a post by others has been edited, clicking on the date that states when it was last edited brings you to the page where you can view the source. Enjoy your stay!

Comment: @Herbert: Just to let you know, now 5 users different from the OP have edited the question (and your edit is really making the code clearer). If one _more_ user edits the question, then it is made "community wiki". This is not a real problem; I just wanted to let you know. (The effect is that no more reputation points can be earned on this question anymore.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a common problem beginners have (I guess). You are writing in the book class, so chapters will only start on right pages (odd page numbers).

So in case one paragraph in a chapter ends on a right page, the next left page (even page number) will be left blank and the new chapter starts on a new right side. If you don't like this behaviour, use `\documentclass[openany]{book}` or use \documentclass{report}. The letter creates one-sided documents that only consists of right pages.

[image]

Comment: Worked perfectly! But another trouble arise: I add another \input command, this time to the cover and sub-cover pages. Another blank page appear. What happen?

Comment: You have to demonstrate this in an example. Usually it does not matter if you \input something or if it is written directly in the main file. Probably you use a package or function that executes/defines and uses something like a \cleardoublepage. As long as you want give an example, however, it will be just guessing...